# Is Ewan McGregor in The Force Awakens? If so, what was his role?

Tags: star-wars, casting, the-force-awakens

I read somewhere that Ewan McGregor was in *The Force Awakens*, but no mention of his role. Was it just a cameo, or some other part? Was he actually in the film?

Comment: You can watch movie for that

Comment: IMDB lists him with " (voice) (uncredited)".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### He's not on screen...but his voice is heard.

> During a flashback scene brought about by Rey touching Luke’s old lightsaber, **a voice is heard whispering the name ‘Rey’.**
>
> It was originally thought that the voice actor who played Kenobi in the Clone Wars TV series, James Arnold Taylor, said the name out loud, yet he revealed on Twitter that director **JJ Abrams got McGregor to overdub his voice**.
>
> JJ Abrams has since confirmed that it is McGregor's voice being heard in the flashback, telling Entertainment Weekly: "You do hear a little bit of Yoda. You hear Luke yelling out, ‘Nooo!’ from that moment in Empire. And you hear Obi-Wan at the end say, ‘Rey … these are your first steps."
>
> He continued: "Here’s the cool part. **We asked Ewan McGregor to come in and do the line** And he was awesome and we were very grateful. He was incredibly sweet and handsome, and all that stuff. Then he rode off on his motorcycle. Literally the coolest voice over actor ever."
>
> <sup>[The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/ewan-mcgregors-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameo-role-revealed-a6780481.html)</sup>

Comment: The `Rey` word was cut out from the word `afraid` said by Alec Guinnes in the old films. The rest is McGregor's.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, he said so in *The Graham Norton Show* - he recorded a little line.

He doesn't know where that line is, but I remember it to be the line from the flashback Rey experiences in Maz Khanata's temple.